How to remove the Fancy header from the Abstract, dedication and acknowledgements and keep the original titles

    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage [ Lenny ]{ fncychap }
% Load blindtext package for dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext}
% Load the setspace package
\usepackage{setspace}
% Using \doublespacing in the preamble 
% changes text to double line spacing
\doublespacing
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reducedspacing}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makeschapterhead\@myreducedmakeschapterhead
  #1
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\@myreducedmakeschapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{-20pt}% Adjust this value to increase or decrease space
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother
% New command for centered, italic titles without page numbers
\newcommand{\centereditalicchapter}[1]{%
  \reducedspacing{%
    \chapter*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  }%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
}

\usepackage{siunitx,letltxmacro}
\usepackage{physics}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Reduce space before and after chapter title
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{20\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{40\p@}{10\p@}{}{}
% Reduce space before and after chapter title in starred chapters
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{20\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{40\p@}{10\p@}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{booktabs} % For top/mid/bottom rules
\usepackage{graphicx} % For resizing tables
\usepackage{adjustbox} % For additional adjustments
\usepackage{caption} % For customizing captions
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For top/mid/bottom rules
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Latin Modern, a widely used font

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tcolorbox} % for creating colored boxes
\usepackage{framed}    % For the framed environment
\usepackage{enumitem}  % For customizing lists
\usepackage{placeins}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, matrix, trees}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{Chapter\thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{section \thesection}  % Section on the right
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcommand{\dedicationpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}% better empty
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \usefont{\encodingdefault}{pzc}{m}{n}
%  \input{frontmatter/dedication}
  %% here I insert directly the code
  \text{This effort is dedicated to our loved ones who left us,}

\\

\text{may their souls rest in peace.}

\\[1.5em]

\text{To the souls of my two beautiful grandmothers}

\\

\text{Rokaia, Hania}

\\

\text{and my beloved uncle Slah.}





  %%
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \clearpage
}
% Define a new fancy style for the bibliography
\fancypagestyle{bibliography}{
    \fancyhead{} % Clears all headers for bibliography
    \fancyfoot{} % Clears all footers
    \fancyfoot[L]{\thepage} % Keep the page number in the footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % No header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} % Footer rule remains the same
}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}


\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}


\parindent 0cm
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\appendixpagenumbering}{
  \break
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exemple}{Example}[chapter]


%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Mots clés---}} #1}
\providecommand{\keywordss}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}

\usepackage{etoolbox}



\usepackage[english]{babel}


% Enable SageTeX to run SageMath code right inside this LaTeX file.
% documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf
%\usepackage{sagetex}


\newcommand{\reportTitle} {%
  \textsc{Modelling And Intelligent Navigation Of a Transport Robot}
  %\textsc{Projet de Fin d'\'etudes}
}

\newcommand{\reportAuthor} {%
  Dhahri Sarra}%


\newcommand{\reportSubject} {%
  Modeling And Intelligent Navigation \\Of a Transport Robot %
}

\newcommand{\dateSoutenance} {%
  25/10/2024%
}

\newcommand{\studyDepartment} {%
  Entreprise d'accueil %Statistique
}

\newcommand{\ESSAI} {%
   National School of Engineers of Carthage
  %Ecole Sup\'erieure de la Statistique et de l'Analyse de l'Information
}

%\newcommand{\codePFE} {% Reference
%  Code PFE%
%}

\newcommand{\juryPresident} {%
  Mr Ben Foulen \textsc{Foulenia}%
}
\newcommand{\juryPresidentDesc} {%
  President%
}

\newcommand{\juryMemberOne} {%
  Ms Ben Foulena \textsc{Foulen}%
}
\newcommand{\juryMemberOneDesc} {%
  Examiner %Mentor
}

\newcommand{\juryMemberTwo} {%
  Mr Ben Foulen \textsc{Fouleni}%
}
\newcommand{\juryMemberTwoDesc} {%
  Reviewer% Examiner, Reporter
}

\newcommand{\juryMemberThree} {%
    M. Ben Foulen \textsc{Fouleni}%
}
\newcommand{\juryMemberThreeDesc} {%
    Supervisor% Examiner, Reporter
}

\newcommand{\juryMemberFour} {%
    M. Ben Foulen \textsc{Fouleni}%
}
\newcommand{\juryMemberFourDesc} {%
    Mentor% Examiner, Reporter
}


\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}}#1\end{tabularx}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Add your own commands here
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\MyCommand} {%
  Does nothing really%
}


% used in maketitle
\title{\reportSubject}
\author{\reportAuthor}

% Enable SageTeX to run SageMath code right inside this LaTeX file.
% documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf
%\usepackage{sagetex}

%\hypersetup{
%  pdftitle={\reportTitle~-~\reportSubject},%
%  pdfauthor={\reportAuthor},%
%  pdfsubject={\reportSubject},%
%  pdfkeywords={report} {internship} {pfe} {enis}
%}


%\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{
  %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  %\fancyhead[L]{}

  %\fancyfoot[R]{\fontsize{12}{12} \thepage}% Right footer
  
  %\fancyfoot[L]{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont UCAR/ESSAI}% Right header

%}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

%%%%%%%%%%%% My style end :p%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\fancypagestyle{plain}{
%  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer

  %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
%  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

  %\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}}% Left header
  %\fancyhead[R]{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\reportAuthor}% Right header

%  \fancyfoot[R]{\fontsize{12}{12}\thepage}% Right footer
  
%  \fancyfoot[L]{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\ UCAR/ESSAI}% Right header

%}

\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{A contrived acronym}
\newacronym{efg}{EFG}{Another acronym}
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machines}

\pagenumbering{roman}
% Define custom tcolorbox style for the algorithm header with reduced padding
\newtcolorbox{myalgorithm}[1][]{
  colback=gray!10!white,
  colframe=gray!70!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=gray!70!black,
  boxrule=1.5pt,
  width=\textwidth,
  arc=3mm,
  #1
}
\newcommand{\Model}{\text{Model}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
   \draw[black, line width=2pt, rounded corners=15pt]
     ($(current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm)$)
     rectangle
     ($(current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% THE HEADER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Adjusting the font size
\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\vspace{-20pt}


% Creating a tabular environment for the layout
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
    % Left Image
    \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=2cm]{Images/logo_enicar.jpg} & 
    % Text in the middle
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        Tunisian Republic \\ 
        Ministry of Higher Education \\ 
        and Scientific Research \\ 
        Carthage University \\ 
       National School of Engineers of Carthage
    \end{tabular} & 
    % Right Image
    \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=2cm]{Images/logo ucar2.png} \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10pt} 



%\arrayrulecolor{reportType}%
%\rule{\textwidth}{.75pt}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\

\vspace{10pt}
{\textit{Submitted to}}\\
\vspace{10pt}
{\bf\large  \ESSAI{}}\\
\vspace{10pt}
\textit{In partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of}\\

\vspace{10pt}
\textbf{\large Master’s Degree in Research} 

\vspace{10pt} % Space added before specialization

\textit{Specialization: Automatics, Robotics, and Information Processing} \\ % Your specialization line
\vspace{3pt} % Minimal space after specialization

\vspace{-10pt} % Space above the horizontal line
{%
  \renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\defaultFont}
  \fontsize{27pt}{32pt}\selectfont%
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\ % Horizontal line
  \reportSubject{}\\ % Title directly under the line with no space
  \vspace{10pt} % Space after the title
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} % Second horizontal line
}\\


\vspace{10pt}
{\textit{Presented by }}\\
\vspace{5pt} {%
  \fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont%
  \textbf{\reportAuthor}\\
}%
\vspace{30pt}
Defended on~\dateSoutenance~ in front of the committee composed of:\\
%Soutenu le \dateSoutenance, devant la commission d'examen:\\
\vspace{20pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth} p{0.15\linewidth}}
  \juryPresident{} & \juryPresidentDesc{}\\
  \juryMemberOne{} & \juryMemberOneDesc{}\\
  \juryMemberTwo{} & \juryMemberTwoDesc{}\\
  \juryMemberThree{} & \juryMemberThreeDesc{}\\
  \juryMemberFour{} & \juryMemberFourDesc{}\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{30pt}%
\textbf{\textit{Academic Year}}\\

\vspace{10pt}
2024-2025\\

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

% Include Abstract
\include{abstract}
% Include Dedication
\include{Dedication}
% Include Acknowledgments
\include{Acknowledgements}

\reducedspacing{\tableofcontents}
\reducedspacing{\listoffigures}
\reducedspacing{\listoftables}



\pagenumbering{arabic}
% Adjust the spacing between sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*1.5}{*0.5}

% Adjust the spacing between subsections
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{*0.25}

\chapter{Introduction }
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{chapter01}

\chapter{Literature Review } 
\input{chapter02}

\chapter{Intelligent Navigation With Reinforcement Learning}
\input{chapter03}

\chapter{Kineamtics, Dynamics Modeling and Control}
\input{chapter04}

\chapter{ Implementations and Results }
\input{chapter05}
\chapter{Conclusions and Perspectives }
\input{conclusion}


\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{BiB}

\end{document}


you need to edit your preamble :-). (1) to ask here, you should include only the packages required by the question and your code shouldn't depend on files we don't have. (2) in your real document, you need to remove packages you don't need. (3) in your real document, you need to change the order in which you load packages. for example, hyperref should come near the end, but cleveref should come after hyperref. (4) don't load packages twice. (5) you are not using lipsum or blindtext. (6) do not use inputenc unless your tex is a couple of decades old. PS don't use \\  to add space.

Unfortunately your code does not compile, because it depends on external files For the same reason it does not result in the shown screenshot. So please, edit your question and try to make your example minimal and complete and take care for a corresponding screenshot that can be replicated using the shown code. Also add some description of the problem to your question. So this is just a guess: Move the \pagestyle{fancy} to the place where it should be used first.
